# Remove public_html from url through htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a legacy project on a server where the actual framework is in a folder above the public_html folder. So the directory structure is like this:

- domainname.com

  - app/
  - framework/
  - public_html/

    - index.php

Now I want to place this on our own server. This is an application created by the hosting company. The root folder is **default**. So now my directory structure is like this:

- default/

  - app/
  - framework/
  - public_html/

    - index.php

Now he's **pointing to the default folder instead of the public_html folder**. That's the only difference with the old version. So I've added a **.htaccess file** to the root folder default. The content of this file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public_html/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In my **public_html** folder I have a **.htaccess** file like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,NS]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA,NS]
```

So when I go to my website it works. But when I click on a link I get: *http://domainname.com/public_html/theclickedpage/*.

But I **don't want the public_html in my url**. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you not just put the app and framework folders level with default in the folder hierarchy and replace default with public_html?

Comment: Please include the URLs you are requesting, and the desired file system path. If you are seeing `public_html` in the links, in the HTML source, then that is something you need to resolve in your application, not `.htaccess`. Including this "legacy project" in the public webspace also raises security concerns. "he's pointing to the default folder" - who's "he"?

Comment: Depends on your code (and server env.), but sometimes I keep the code as is, and create a symlink from the web root.  Something like: `default/index.php` to `public_html/index.php`, which could be outside your document root.

Comment: What is your HTML source code for the link. Do you have `<a href='/public_html/page' ...>` in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search for a way to make a virtual host. I know some of my webhost let me configure the vhost through my admin page. It will let your server consider the url without including the specified folder, but back in the stage it performs needed redirection.

Comment: How does "Laravel" fit into this?

Comment: My bad, thought I saw the Laravel tag and the public folder reminded me of Lar !

Answer (score 0):

You applied correct rule ,

but the problem is link for the solution of this issue you have to
remove public_html from
your all links and it will automatically redirect to your required 
path without public_html.